# CantOpenException when migrating SQLite3 to PostgreSQL on Windows using 'taps' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, sequel

I am trying to migrate a SQLite3 database to a PostgreSQL database using the 'taps' gem ( https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps ), as described in [Change from SQLite to PostgreSQL in a fresh Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710654/how-do-you-easily-change-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-rails) and in http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

I have a Windows 7 machine, have a Rails app in c:\Sites\MySite, and the database in c:\Sites\MySite\db\development.sqlite3

Whenever I try to start the taps server, I get this exception:

> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:62:in
>   `initialize': SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file
>   (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)

Here's what I tried (all tried while running the command prompt with Administrator privileges):

```
rem From C:\Sites\MySite:
taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 eo secret
taps server sqlite:///db/development.sqlite3 eo secret
taps server sqlite://c:/sites/mysite/db/development.sqlite3 eo secret
taps server sqlite:///c:/sites/mysite/db/development.sqlite3 eo secret
rem From C:\Sites\MySite\db:
taps server sqlite://development.sqlite3 eo secret
taps server sqlite:///development.sqlite3 eo secret
```

None of the above worked. Documentation for the taps gem did not prove helpful. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates the file couldn't be opened, but at least a couple of the connection strings you provided should work.

You could try doing the following from `C:\Sites\MySite` (uses Sequel directly, not taps):

```
sequel -C sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 postgres://user:pass@host/database
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked! (Running into another issue while copying the database, but I'm pretty sure it's unrelated - at least the connection works ok now)