# Timestamp breaks sqlite3 import to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, taps

I have a rails app that I used Sqlite3 for the db, but am now switching to use Postgresql.

Per [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710654/how-do-you-easily-change-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-rails), I have set up the postgresql databases, and am now importing the sqlite3 db's to postgres using the taps gem.

The problem is: My sqlite3 db has a column :time, in which I store unix timestamps (integers). The postgres schema says they are 'timetstamp without time zone' however, and are rejecting the current values. This is the error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "time" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type integer (Sequel::DatabaseError)LINE 1: ..."address_type", "medical") VALUES (2, 2, 0, NULL, 1367688600...
```

How do you get around this? Do I need to convert all the time entries in my sqlite3 database to match the postgres schema? Also, since this is only for my dev db, it's not a problem to drop the db values entirely and start afresh -- so if there is an easy way to do this too, I would appreciate knowing that.

Comment: I just realized after booting up the app, that it actually works now, and is just using the empty postgresql db's (schema got imported via taps, I guess -- just not data). Can I just proceed, or should I destroy those old sqlite3 db's and if so how do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

To convert the value back you will need to run it through a query like:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + timecol * INTERVAL '1 second';
```

So what I would do is change your schema in PostgreSQL to make these columns integers.   Then I would run them through a job that would add a new timestamp column, and run the above query on it (where timecol is the column name of the old timestamp).  Then, once you have spot-checked the data, you can drop the old column and rename the new column to the old name.

Comment: And in a Rails environment, you'd either do this stuff by hand via `psql` or, um, do it by hand by stuffing a bunch of SQL into `connection.execute` calls.