# Converting from SQLITE3 to postgres for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I know there are numerous topics on this. I have tried them all to no success. Note, I do not need to maintain my previous data. I just need my app to work in Heroku.

Following this guide, this is one thing I've tried
[Change from SQLite to PostgreSQL in a fresh Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710654/change-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-a-fresh-rails-project)

So I have my application that works using sqlite3.

Go into 'gemfile' and change

`gem 'sqlite3'` into  `gem 'pg'`

run `$ bundle` in terminal (to change Gemfile.lock)

Go to my `database.yml` file and replace it with

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

test: &TEST
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_test
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

cucumber:
  <<: *TEST
```

I then pushed this to github.

On the Heroku website I connect the github directory to my app and deploy it.

It successfully deploys but the page only says

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

I am pretty certain I am missing a step as whenever I try to run it on my local machine it says

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError

FATAL: database "project_development" does not exist

Extracted source (around line #661):

659 rescue ::PG::Error => error
660   if error.message.include?("does not exist")
661     raise ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError.new(error.message, error)
662   else
663     raise
664   end
```

--

EDIT

When I input

```
heroku run rake db:create
```

I get the response

▸    Error: No app specified
 ▸    Usage: heroku run --app APP
 ▸    We don't know which app to run this on.
 ▸    Run this command from inside an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP

When I run

```
heroku run rake db:create -app nguyen-andrew-a2
```

I get the response

Running rake db:create nguyen-andrew-as2 on ⬢ pp... !!!
 ▸    Couldn't find that app.
Macbook-Pro-5:try2 andrew$

--

On my local machine, after running it the page now says

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Extracted source (around line #651):
649 # connected server's characteristics.
650 def connect
651    @connection = PGconn.connect(@connection_parameters)
652
653    # Money type has a fixed precision of 10 in PostgreSQL 8.2 and below, and as of
654    # PostgreSQL 8.3 it has a fixed precision of 19. PostgreSQLColumn.extract_precision
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change from SQLite to PostgreSQL in a fresh Rails project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710654/change-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-a-fresh-rails-project)

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `rake db:create` on your local machine and on Heroku?
Try these steps:

- `bundle exec rake db:create`
- `bundle exec rake dg:migrate`
- `bundle exec rails s`

For Heroku, just add `heroku run` before any command, like this: `heroku run rake db:create`, and `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: I have edited my initial question to respond to you. Formatting in comments is hard.

Comment: Did you create user for the database? Try this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the `couldn't find that app` error, that means that you passed an invalid app name as the `-a, --app` option for the heroku command. Valid app names are obtained with the `heroku apps` command.

I also see that you ran `... -app <app-name> ...` instead of `... --app <app-name> ...`, which is likely to cause errors. Try the following command replacement:

```
// before
heroku run rake db:create -app nguyen-andrew-a2
// after
heroku run rake db:create --app nguyen-andrew-a2
```